# Quais tags deveríamos usar/manter para quando uma pergunta é relacionada ao upload de arquivos?

Tags: debate, tags

Hoje fui responder uma pergunta sobre [**upload de arquivos**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260571/66203), e reparei que temos algumas tags relacionadas ao assunto:

- [file-upload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-upload) - 145 perguntas, *tag* relacionada à funcionalidades/componentes relacionados ao upload de arquivos (indiferente do tipo de arquivo, como planilhas, imagens, textos, etc).
- [upload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upload) - 255 perguntas, "Carregar" ou "Subir" (upload) refere-se ao envio de dados de um sistema local para um sistema remoto, como um servidor ou outro cliente com a intenção de que o sistema remoto armazene uma cópia dos dados que estão sendo transferidos.

"*Teoricamente*", acredito que elas sejam a mesma coisa, não? Quando você vai realizar um *upload*, você escolhe um *file* ("arquivo").

- Então elas não poderiam ser sinônimos? Se não existe alguma diferenciação de uso? Alguma *guideline* específica para quando usar cada uma delas?

Comment: Ambas são desnecessárias ao meu ver e mesmo que o assunto fosse estritamente sobre o que é upload ainda sim seria tão raro que seria inútil uma tag para tão poucas perguntas, ambas ao meu ver devem deixar de existir.